# How to use Prism plugins installed with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, prism.js

I'm using prism to show my documentation. So there I went to show some beautiful code. To install prism there is two ways: manual install, or with node.
I used node to install it. But to use its plugins there is no doc that explain how:
the only available example is:

```
var code = "var data = 1;";
var html = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.javascript);
```

and then show the html...
in my case I want to use the line numbers. How to?

Comment: Yeah the documentation for using node is appallingly poor. Really really bad.

Answer (score 4):

In your html create the following:

```
<pre class="line-numbers"><code id="formattedBlock" class="language-javascript"></code></pre>
```

Do not forget to import related CSS files in the header

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/prism.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/plugins/prism-line-numbers.css" />
```

Make sure you require the neccessary libraries

```
var Prism = require('prismjs/components/prism-core.min');
require('prismjs/components/prism-javascript.min');
require('prismjs/plugins/line-numbers/prism-line-numbers.min');
```

After what example you wrote is correct:

```
var code = "var data = 1;";
var html = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages.javascript);
```

Just append the html result into formattedBlock element e.g. with jQuery:

```
$('#formattedBlock').append(html);
```

Comment: I still don't understand how this works with npm programmatically... without using jquery and an id for each code block.